# ¿Cómo desactivar botón sin refrescar la ventana?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, asp.net-mvc-5

Usando javascript, ¿cómo puedo desactivar un `button` sin refrescar o antes de resfrescar la ventana?:

Este es el código javascript que tengo hasta el momento:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#confirmacion-validar-impresion").click(function() {
                        var form = $("form#ValidarImpresion").serializeArray();

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "post",
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: 'ValidarImpresion',
                            data: form,
                            success: function(response) {
                                console.log(response);
                            }
                        });
```

```
if (@Model.impreso) == false {
    //imprimir
    <
    button id = "boton"
    type = "button"
    class = "btn btn-primary"
    data - toggle = "modal"
    data - target = "#carne-preview-modal" > Imprmir < /button>
} else {
    //No imprimir
    <
    button id = "boton"
    type = "button"
    class = "btn btn-primary"
    data - toggle = "modal"
    data - dismiss ">Imprmir</button>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Para desactivar un botón basta con agregarle el atributo `disabled`.

```
$("#id-del-boton").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Esto hace que el botón se vuelva "gris" y no puede ser clickeado.

Luego si quieres volver a habilitarlo, simplemente eliminas el atributo.

```
$("#id-del-boton").removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

para desactivar un botón sin refrescar primero tienes que crear un watch que cuando modifiques el valor puedas preguntar si es el que quieres... por ejemplo si vas a habilitar el botón de enviar cuando todos los campos de un formulario estén correctos...
Si pudieras ser más explicito en lo que quieres...cuando es que quieres deshabilitar el botón?
Si es cuando estén correctos todos los datos de un formulario te recomiendo que uses jqueryvalidate(https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: okay que pasa yo tengo bloqueado para que el usuario no pueda actualizar o refrescar la pagina, entonces necesito deshabilitar un boton que esta validando una informacion. con If else. Por ejemplo: Si se imprimio un carnet que no se vuelva a imprimir nuevamente y se deshabilite el boton de inmediato sin tener que hacer refresh!